# Efficiently load image for "center" scaling

Tags: android, android-widget

I have full-sized image files stored on the phone's filesystem, and a method for loading a thumbnail version to be used in a `ListView`. I basically use the sub-sampling technique that is discussed often on SO and also [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html).

The method outlined in the link requires you to provide a target width and height in pixels for the sub-sampling to work. For my list view, this is fine because the thumbnail width/height are defined as dimension resources, and are easily converted to pixels. The `ImageView` that these are loaded into use a `scaleXY` scale type.

In addition to the list view, I have a separate detailed view where I want to display the selected image as a banner at the top of the screeen, but using a scale type of `center` (no resizing). The target `ImageView` is within a `RelativeLayout` with a fixed height (set in the resources area), and the width set to `fill_parent`.

So I have 3 questions:

1. Given that I don't want any special resizing done on the banner image (`scaleType` is set to `center`), is the sub-sampling technique still applicable here?
2. If the answer to #1 is **yes**, then I would need to be able to calculate the target view's width. Since the width (unlike the height) of the target `ImageView` isn't fixed like the thumbnail view, how can I find what the effective width the `fill_parent` ends up as?
3. If the answer to #1 is **no**, then how can I efficiently load this image into the view without risking a memory exception?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you taken a look at [android-query](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/#Image_Loading)?

Comment: That does look very handy, and maybe I'll use it, but given that I'm just doing this stuff to learn, I would still love to know the answer.